# help with finding roots using excel or matlab

Tags: functions, matlab

I've been asked to finding the roots of the equation $x^3-6x+2=0$. They've called it the 'pivot method' but I can't seem to find the 'real' name of it. I've looked at secant, newton, bisection etc... and nothing seems to match this. The method is as follows:

To solve $f(x)=0$, select $2$ $x$'s values between which the exact solution lies, say $x=a$ and $x=b$. Draw vertical lines through $x=a$ and $x=b$ to meet $f(x)$ at $P$ and $Q$. The point where $\overline{PQ}$ cuts the $x$ axis appears to be a better approximation to the exact solution than either $x=a$ and $x=b$. consider this new point $x=c$. Then basically this repeats and a vertical is drawn at $x=c$ to meet the curve and then it gets connected to the top point and where that cuts the $x$ axis is a better approximation again.

If anyone knows what this method is called or understands it please help! Thanks

Comment: actually is this the false position method?

Comment: Some detail about the algorithm is not supplied (what is the top point?)  but this looks like the Secant Method.

Comment: It seems like the secant method to me except the "vertical line" part. If we were to use vertical lines then we might end up with progressively worse approximations (?).

Comment: Hi sorry I couldn't figure out how to attach a image but I have a link to it now. https://twitter.com/Lisaban_/status/758086277711355904 Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the False Position method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method ?

Comment: And use the anti-stalling variants mentioned. Pure regula falsi can be worse than the bisection method due to stalling, i.e., one interval end-point, though far from the root, does not move.